# Export client certificate from Let's Encrypt certificates

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm running `Debian` and have `certbot` for creating `Let's Encrypt` certificate.

I act as client towards a TLS server, and needs to handover my client certificate for approval.

I've got the following files generated by `certbot`:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/privkey.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/chain.pem
```

Which certificate should I handover, and is it safe to share public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/privkey.pem` private as it contains the private key for your certificate.

You can hand out one ofthese two files:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/chain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/fullchain.pem
```

You might want to share the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-client-server-domain/fullchain.pem` as it contains intemediate certificates if those were used by Let's Encrypt. The recipient can extract your certificate from it in case it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `certbot certificates` sub command to display your certificate files if you don't exactly know which file(s) you need. You can use the `-d [hostname]` option if you have more than hostname/domainname configured:

```
certbot certificates -d www.example.com

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found the following matching certs:

  Certificate Name: server.example.com
    Domains: server.example.com mail.example.com www.example.com example.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-09-30 12:45:28+00:00 (VALID: 82 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example.com/fullchain.pem   <====
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example.com/privkey.pem


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In any [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) you only need to keep the aptly named *"Private Key"* data private and secure, and you can (and usually must) share the public key/certificate freely, so share the `fullchain.pem` file from what `certbot` calls the *"certificate path"*.